# Handle pending promise while using async await

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have two time taking functions -> getExcelFileStream and loadWorkbook

I want the function structure to return a response(pass/failure) only after both these subfunctions have been executed.
But it always returns a promise pending clause.

```
async function parseToJson(data) {

    const excelFileStream = await getExcelFileStream(data.url);
    const dataRows = await loadWorkbook(excelFileStream, data.orgId);

    return dataRows;

}

exports.uploadExcel = function uploadExcel(data) {
    return parseToJson(data);
};
```

Comment: How are you calling your function ?

Comment: the return value of `parseToJson` is a Promise - hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) *(Syntax > Return value)*

> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

So it should be

```js
exports.uploadExcel = async function uploadExcel(data) {
  return await parseToJson(data)
}
```

Comment: I think you should be able to simplify this to be just `exports.uploadExcel = parseToJson`

Comment: Yes. But this is called in my services module. So if I change the servicefunction to be an async function, I will have to change my controller, Router and subsequently till my authCalls.
Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: even with `return await`, it will still return a promise

Comment: `return await` as the only `await` in an `async` function is redundant - remove `async` and `await` for clean code

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make an asynchronous code synchronous in javascript, and with javascript being single threaded, you can't write code to wait for the promise without blokcing the execution of the code handling the promise itself.

I am guessing when you're calling your function `uploadExcel`, you don't have any `await` or a `.then()` so you get a promise instead of the value of the resolved promise.

Unfortunately, You only have two options:
1- Let `async/await` propagates all the way up in your code
2- Make all your code synchronous, and that would be a very bad idea.